# Why docker run `--oom-kill-disable` is not effective , but `echo 1 > memory.oom_control` is effective in myself System！

Tags: docker, cgroups

When I run one container for docker run --oom-kill-disable, it is not effective; But when I "echo 1 > memory.oom_control", it is effective.

```
docker version:
Client:
 Version:   17.12.0-ce
 API version:   1.35
 Go version:    go1.9.2
 Git commit:    c97c6d6
 Built: Wed Dec 27 20:05:38 2017
 OS/Arch:   linux/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:  17.12.0-ce
  API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.2
  Git commit:   c97c6d6
  Built:    Wed Dec 27 20:12:29 2017
  OS/Arch:  linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

```
1.sudo docker run -it --memory=100M --oom-kill-disable MyselfImage /bin/bash
2.stress --vm 1 --vm-bytes 200M #stress process is killed
stress: info: [42] dispatching hogs: 0 cpu, 0 io, 1 vm, 0 hdd
stress: FAIL: [42] (415) <-- worker 43 got signal 9
stress: WARN: [42] (417) now reaping child worker processes
stress: FAIL: [42] (451) failed run completed in 1s
3.echo 1 > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/XXX/memory.oom_control
4.stress --vm 1 --vm-bytes 200M #stress process is not killed
stress: info: [42] dispatching hogs: 0 cpu, 0 io, 1 vm, 0 hdd
...
```

Why the memory.oom_control file is not changed by `--oom-kill-disable` param.

Comment: Seems to be a bug... In `19.03.7` everything works as expected (Arch). Could you try to test it in different environment?

Comment: @DanilaKiver OK, I will try!

Answer (score 0):

When I try docker 19.03.7, it works! so, this question is a bug in my docker(17.12.0-ce)

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.7
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        7141c199a2
 Built:             Wed Mar  4 01:19:42 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.7
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       7141c199a2
  Built:            Wed Mar  4 01:19:50 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```