# Why `oom-kill-disable` is not effective for `kubectl create pod`, but is effective for `docker run container ` in myself System?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cgroups

I want to forbid k8s pod is oom killed when memory is used totally, first I tried it by docker run, it works; but when I tried it by kubectl, it failed!

[docker run][docker run -ti -m 256M --oom-kill-disable myselfImage bash]
[docker set oom-kill-disable success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60735110/why-docker-run-oom-kill-disable-is-not-effective-but-echo-1-memory-oom/60735825#60735825)

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.5", GitCommit:"2166946f41b36dea2c4626f90a77706f426cdea2", GitTreeState:"archive", BuildDate:"2019-07-30T03:39:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"", Minor:"", GitVersion:"v0.0.0-master+2166946f41b36d", GitCommit:"2166946f41b36dea2c4626f90a77706f426cdea2", GitTreeState:"", BuildDate:"2019-08-21T08:42:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

docker version = 19.03.7
```

```
oom.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: oom-test
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/hostname: "hostname"
  containers:
  - name: oom-test
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        add: ["SYS_ADMIN", "SYS_RESOURCE", "IPC_LOCK"]
    image: myselfImage
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /dev/shm
      name: cache-volume
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "4"
        memory: "10Gi"
      requests:
       cpu: "4"
       memory: "10Gi"
  volumes:
  - name: cache-volume
    emptyDir:
      medium: Memory
      sizeLimit: "5Gi"
  restartPolicy: Never
```

```
1.echo 1 > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/kubepods/memory.oom_control
2.kubectl create -f oom.yaml
3.kubectl exec -ti oom-test bash
>>stress --vm 1 --vm-bytes 10G #pod is oom killed
NAME                     READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
devmachine-shm-test-02   0/1     OOMKilled   0          2m45s
```

Why pod is oom killed even if I set `echo 1 > memory.oom_control`

Comment: How did you create your cluster? You have `Client version 1.13` which is quite old and `Server version ""` is none? Do you have your cluster on localhost or On-Prem? Do you have enough resources to run this pod (10Gi memory and 4 CPUs)? Did you consider to upgrade your Kubernetes version to the newest? Its Kubeadm, Minikube, something else?

Comment: We created our cluster by compiling k8s source code, and we have enough machine and the machines's memory and CPUs is enough for this test，so resources is not the problem; I will consider to upgrade our Kubernetes version to be the newest.@PjoterS

Answer (score 1):

When I add `--cgroup-driver=cgroupfs` for kubelet config, it works!
So I think this question maybe myself kubelet config problem.